# How SSL server handle multiple connections?

Tags: ssl

On the law lvl of [SSL protocols](http://blog.fourthbit.com/2014/12/23/traffic-analysis-of-an-ssl-slash-tls-session) there are 4 types of messages:

- Handshake Protocol
- ChangeCipherSpec Protocol
- Alert Protocol
- Application Data Protocol

After the handshaking is completed and the symmetric private key been exchanged, the client will send **Application Data** messages to the server.

How ever same server can handle multiple clients, and each of those clients got it's own symmetric key.

Does the server keeps the connection open with all of the clients? If not how does the server know what symmetric key to use for an incoming connection? Does **Application Data Protocol** provide some sort of session id that the server can use to map to the right key?

Comment: You are searching for the TLS SessionTicket.

Comment: @Robert no the ticket is part of ClientHello. Client also send application data message that contains the actual content(encrypted), how does the server know what key to use to decrypt it?

Comment: It has a TLS session cache, often file-based.

Comment: @Robert can you please link me, because what you are saying is usually referred to session key used to restore sessions and it's part of the Hello message, also it require a lot of space on the server and so it been optimized with Session Tickets where the session data is stored on the client side. So do you refer to session id that is part of Server/Client Hello or is it part of Application Data

Comment: There are two possibilities: If it uses the TLS SessionTicket everything is contained in the ticket (see e.g. RFC 5077 page 10), If the server uses session-ids the session cache on server-side is used.

Comment: @Robert dude it's not what I am asking, I want to understand the application data message, or are you saying that before each application data message you need to do a handshake?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the server keeps the connection open with all of the clients?

It can, depending on how the server is implemented.

> how does the server know what symmetric key to use for an incoming connection?

Imagine you have a multiplayer game. Your server code typically looks something like this:

```
sock = socket.listen(port)
clients = []
if sock.new_client_waiting:
    new_client = sock.accept()
    clients.append(new_client)

for client in clients:
    if client.new_data_waiting:
        data = client.read()
        # handle incoming actions...
```

So if there are two clients, the server will just know about both and have a *socket object* for both. Therein lies your answer: the OS (its TCP stack) handles the concept of connections and by providing you a socket, you can read/write from and to that socket, and you know from which clients it originates (to some degree of certainty anyway).

Many servers work differently, e.g. web server code is much more like this:

```
sock = socket.listen(port)
while True: # infinitely loop...
    client = sock.accept() # This call will block until a client is available
    spawn_new_http_handler(client)
```

Whenever a new person connects, a worker thread will pick it up and manage things from there. But still, it will have its socket to read from and write to.

> Does Application Data Protocol provide some sort of session id that the server can use to map to the right key?

I do not know these specs by heart, but I am pretty sure the answer is **no**. Session resumption is done earlier, at the handshake stage, and is meant for clients returning. E.g. if I connected to https://example.com 30 minutes ago and return now, it might have my session and we don't need to do the whole handshake again. It doesn't have anything to do with telling clients apart.

Comment: I completely understand the way it works, given all the communication with the client is done over one socket, but from what I understand http/1.1 is about opening a connection, making a request and closing the connection(Not sure how the keep-alive header comes in play...), so for each client request new socket will be created. When I inspected a random website with Wireshark, I only saw the handshake once and it fallowed with many Application Data messages, even so I refreshed the page. I believe that new socket been made for each application data message.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Then it is using session resumption. If you are sure that it only used Application Data messages for that, then session resumption must be implemented in Application Data messages.